# Overwrite core layout in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to overwrite related product design,I need to show greed except of related 
product below product detail page here is related product image but I need to show greed there so  what should I do ?

[image]

I have used core layout in my custom module layout and edited it like.

--> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
</head>
<body> 
    <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
        <block class="Ktpl\Relatedprod\Block\Relatedprod" name="catalog.product.relatedadd" template="Ktpl_Relatedprod::items.phtml"> 
            <arguments>
                <argument name="typeadd" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer> 
</body>
```

But the problem is I am unable to overwrite it.

Comment: Have you defined items.phtml file inside app/code/ktpl/relatedprod/view/frontend/templates/items.phtml file

Comment: Yes I have defined it in my template folder and I am getting both changes mine items.phtml and core items.phtml and need to overwrite core items.phtml please suggest me ..

Comment: please show your path for phtml file and layout file of folder.

Comment: My layout path:-  /app/code/Ktpl/Relatedprod/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml


                               AND  My template path:- /app/code/Ktpl/Relatedprod/view/frontend/templates/items.phtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**catalog_product_view.xml** file content,

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Ktpl_Relatedprod::items.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
    <arguments>
        <argument name="typeadd" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

**etc/frontend/di.xml file,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" type="Ktpl\Relatedprod\Block\Related" />    
</config>
```

**Inside Block file Related.php**,

```
<?php

namespace Ktpl\Relatedprod\Block;

    class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related
    {

        // do code here for customization
        //you can override default function or add new function from here

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only add your block inside `content.aside` this block will get merge to it and all of its content will get rendered.

If you want to override it you can use preference to override related block with your block so that every object request to core block will rewrites to your block. so first you extend your block from related block rewrite it with preference and then add your logic of grid formation inside that block.

Comment: I did this but unable to overwrite

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
   <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related">
        <block class="Ktpl\Relatedprod\Block\Relatedprod" name="relatedprod.prod" template="Ktpl_Relatedprod::items.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>

Comment: Did you used preference ?